# sort post types by amount of views

Tags: custom-post-types, sort, views

I have a custom post type that I want to do a type of news feed for, but I only want to show the ones with the most views. I know I can do a query for an "archive" of my post types, but my question is "how to sort the query by views"?

Comment: What software do you use to count the views? You should not use the WP data base, so there must be some other service with an API for that (like Piwik or Google Analytics).

Comment: @toscho I thought that wordpress tracked views already, but it looks like I was mistaken. I'll likely use something like http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/

Comment: I strongly recommend not to write into your post meta table on each view: Your site will become **very** slow. You have to break all proxy caches too. Just don't do this.

Comment: @toscho What would you recommend for a site with a potential for a lot of traffic? I don't think google analytics will work because I need this data to pull from :(

Comment: I recommend [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) for statistics, it offers a nice API and there are also plugins on wp.org for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WP post views](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/) plugin already does this job very well.

So just install that plugin , then use function like this

```
<?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php get_most_viewed('custom post type name',20); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For more info, check [this FAQ page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/faq/)

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will helpful...

```
    $right_now = gmdate("Y-m-d");
$qstr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, 
    (select postid, sum(pageviews) pageviews 
     from $pageviews_table 
     where day >= '$right_now' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
     group by postid) pv
    WHERE wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post'
    AND wposts.ID = pv.postid
    AND wposts.post_date >= '$right_now' - INTERVAL 30 DAY
    ORDER BY pv.pageviews DESC
    LIMIT 10
 ";

$max_most_read = 5; // Number of "most read-spots" 
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($qstr);
if ($posts) {
   $i = 0;
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        if ($i < $max_most_read) {
                $category = get_the_category();
                $i++;
        }
    }
}
```